# Where is Grub boot loader installed on the computer?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

Where is **Grub boot loader** installed on the computer?

As after removing the ubuntu partition from a dual boot system, Grub is still launched by default. So it couldn't be installed in the partition where Ubuntu is stored.